# android- make a listview grow upwards only

Tags: android, listview, chat

Im creating an in app chat and I cant figure out how to keep the listview I have implemented to keep from growing down below the edittext box I set up to take user chat. Whats happening now is that new lines add to the listview just fine but after the list grows large enough it starts to add to itself below the edittext box. I find that pretty annoying and imagine a user would too so my question is:

How can I keep a listview from growing downwards.

Id like for new fields/text to add to the bottom of the listview but be placed ontop of the edittext just like any normal chat would do.

Comment: I thought I would mention that Ive already tried to use  android:stackFromBottom="true" but that didnt work for me. Rows in the list keep adding below the edittext box i have set up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy, simply set the transcriptMode. If you do it from XML, you have the choice between normal and alwaysScroll:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:transcriptMode

This is how the built-in Google Talk and SMS/MMS applications are implemented (they use the normal transcript mode.)

Comment: Oh wow I actually got Romain Guy to answer one of my questions :) Hey thanks so much for the help with that Im going to try it out right now :)

Comment: you were right....of course :) but I had to set it up with android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"